# What's the best way to have a GWT Presenter with a javaScript view?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I'm using GWT but 1 of my Ui programmers only knows javaScript but is learning Java right now. So what is the best way to have a javaScript view. I tried to use GWT exporter but I had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134510/gwt-exporter-cast-exception-from-gwt-create-tried-to-use-mvp4g-with-gwt-exporte) with it. I've heard that using GWT as glue code and doing the Ui in javaScript is common but I don't see any examples. I'd like to know the best practices for this.

Comment: Generally mixing GWT and JS may be a bad idea in the long run (despite of the fact that GWT supports this pattern by using JSNI) because your team may end up with complete mess in the code.

Comment: I think the greatest thing about MVP is that it makes the view very simple and decouples the view from the rest of the application. However, I agree that the code would be a mess if I used js in the complicated scenarios that are more tightly coupled to the rest of the application. Fortunately, I'll se it for simple self contained things. For example, I have to make a simple form for uploading something. This is very self contained and simple.